# Deleting Billion records in a range vs exact ID lookup MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, sql-delete

I have a database table which is around 700GB with `1 Billion` rows, the data is approximately 500 GB and index is 200GB,
I am trying to delete all the data before 2021,
Roughly around `298,970,576` rows in 2021 and there are `708,337,583` rows remaining.

To delete this I am running a non-stop query in my python shell

`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id < 1762163840 LIMIT 1000000;`

id -> 1762163840 represent data from 2021. Deleting 1Mil row taking almost 1200-1800sec.

Is there any way I can speed up this because the current way is running for more than 15 days and there is not much data delete so far and it's going to do more days.

I thought that if I make a table with just ids of all the records that I want to delete and then do an exact map like

`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM _tmp_table_name);`

Will that be fast? Is it going to be faster than first making a new table with all the records and then deleting it?

The database is setup on RDS and instance class is **db.r3.large** 2 vCPU and 15.25 GB RAM, only 4-5 connections running.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest recreating the data you want to keep -- if you have enough space:

```
create table keep_data as
    select *
    from table_name
    where id >= 1762163840;
```

Then you can truncate the table and re-insert new data:

```
truncate table table_name;

insert into table_name
    select *
    from keep_data;
```

This will recreate the index.

The downside is that this will still take a while to re-insert the data (renaming `keep_data` would be faster).  But it should be much faster than deleting the rows.

AND . . . this will give you the opportunity to *partition* the table so future deletes can be handled much faster.  You should look into table partitioning if you have such a large table.

Comment: Swapping the two table names would be better than truncating and copying back.

Comment: Yes, INSERTING eligible data to a new table and then renaming that table to main table name would be much efficient if your current data is of less volume than archive data.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple techniques for big deletes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

It points out that `LIMIT 1000000` is unnecessarily big and causes more locking than might be desirable.

In the long run, `PARTITIONing` would be beneficial, it mentions that.

If you do Gordon's technique (rebuilding table with what you need), you lose access to the table for a long time; I provide an alternative that has essentially zero downtime.

`id IN (SELECT...)` can be terribly slow -- both because of the inefficiency of in-SELECT and due to the fact that DELETE will hang on to a huge number of rows for transactional integrity.